# Cannot import JS module

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I'm having a seamingly simple JS test project, which is inspired by this blog post:

https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/write-a-javascript-library-using-webpack-and-babel/

- JS file meant to be used as `"module"`. It is contained in `./src/index.js`
- `./index.html` used to consume the module
- There is `./webpack.config.js`, `package.json` and `.babelrc`

My `./package.json` contains these `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
```

Content of `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    library: 'MyModule',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'development',
};
```

Content of `.babelrc`:

```
{
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Content of `./src/index.js`:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor")
    }

    doSomething = () => {
        console.log("Do something")
    }
}

export { Test }
```

Content of `./index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./dist/index_bundle.js"></script>
  <script>
    console.log(MyModule)
    let test = new MyModule.Test()
    test.doSomething()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Browser output OK:

```
index.js:15 Constructor
index.js:13 Do something
```

So far so good. But - I need to have the code using `MyModule` in another JS script.

I created `./index.js`:

```
import { MyModule } from './dist/index_bundle.js'
console.log(MyModule)
```

and altered `./index.html`, so that it loads now `./index.js` instead of doing it directly in `./index.html`:

```
<body>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

First error I got was:

```
caught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I tagged the `./index.js` script entry with `type="module"`:

```
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

The first error was replaced by:

```
caught SyntaxError: The requested module './dist/index_bundle.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

And this is literally the situation I'm stuck. I tried everything:

- made my module `export default Test`
- made my `./index.js` `import MyModule from ...` and several other variations to no avail.

I'm now wondering, why it worked from a script tag inside `./index.html`, but not from `./index.js`.

This is producing the same error:

```
<body>
  <script type="module">
    import { MyModule } from './dist/index_bundle.js'
    console.log(MyModule)
  </script>
</body>
```

Any pointer welcome.

Comment: I tend to accept that it is not possible. I think I have to live with loading the module via index.html and then use exported name

Comment: [`libraryTarget: "umd"`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#librarytarget-umd) causes webpack to compile your modules to [UMD](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/10/04/what-are-umd-modules/), which doesn't use ES module `export`/`import` syntax. One key feature (not the only one) of webpack is to compile all of your modules (using whatever syntax you choose) into browser compatible JS. If you just want to use raw ES modules, then it's possible you don't even need webpack.

Comment: Thanks. Basically all MyModule uses ES6 import/export syntax. I just wanted to have a way to "import" MyModule from another JS module. That's not going to work with this webpack bundling. What works is to load MyModule via index.html and use it in e.g. index.js w/o further "import"